# I can't make corners of images and buttons rounded

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage, calayer

I'm creating the cells of a UITableViewController.
In one of them, a small image is contained. I tried the following to make its corners rounded:

```
profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
profileImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

In another cell prototype, I tried to make the corners of a button rounded:

```
    chooseImageFromRoll.clipsToBounds = YES;
    chooseImageFromRoll.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
```

In both cases I included

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

The button and the image whose corners must be rounded are property of the UITableViewController owning them:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface profileRegistrationCellVC : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *profileImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *chooseImageFromRoll;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *shootImage;

@end
```

In relative .m class:

```
#import "profileRegistrationCellVC.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation profileRegistrationCellVC
@synthesize profileImage;
@synthesize chooseImageFromRoll;
@synthesize shootImage;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        chooseImageFromRoll.clipsToBounds = YES;
        chooseImageFromRoll.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
        shootImage.layer.cornerRadius = 8;

        profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
        profileImage.clipsToBounds = YES;

        profileImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        profileImage.layer.borderWidth = 20.0;

        [self addSubview:profileImage];
        [self addSubview:chooseImageFromRoll];
        [self addSubview:shootImage];


    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Here's the code of my function cellForRowAtIndexPath, in my uitableviewcontroller:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"profileRegistrationCell";

        profileRegistrationCellVC *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[profileRegistrationCellVC alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        //cell.profileImage.image.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        //cell.profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;

        return cell;

    }

    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"regularRegistrationCell";

        regularRegistrationCellVC *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[regularRegistrationCellVC alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.regularFieldName.text = [_registrationItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if ([[_registrationItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Email*"])
            cell.regularTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;

        if ([[_registrationItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Età"]) {
            cell.regularTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
        }

        return cell;

    }

    else{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"orientationRegistrationCell";

        orientationRegistrationCellVC *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[orientationRegistrationCellVC alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.fieldLabel.text = [_registrationItems objectAtIndex:[_registrationItems count]-1];
        cell.orientationLabel.text = @"Non specificato";
        return cell;

    }
}
```

But in no case I managed to make corners rounded. Can you tell where I'm mistaking?

Thanks

Comment: The codes I provided are first for creating a button and the second is for rounding the corners of the uiimage. By using both masks and defining corner radius if you impliment it in the cellfprrowatindexpath method where you access your custom cell it should work. Just add the masks or the radius method inside the method before you return the cell. Also please post your cellforrowat index path of the tableview so I can see what you did.

Comment: i edited my post to add cellForRowAtIndexPath code.
i forgot to specify that buttons and image i have to round have been created from storyboard. the latter already have a background color and a title, but i specified through storyboard interface that they are custom buttons. does all this affect my code? does my code get ineffective? thanks

Comment: moreover: i tried to roound corners and images from the UItablecell controller, since it's the cell to contain them. i don't know whether it would be more correct to do it in cellForRowAtIndexPath, where that particular kind of cell is created

Comment: i moved code for rounding where i cretae cells. it seems to work. thanks ;)

Comment: Great, so happy you finally did it. Your welcome. If you wish you can check my answer as the correct one. And let me know if I could help in the future.:)

Comment: sincerely, now i have to modify the buttons in uiimagepickercontroller.
you help would be welcome. i'm gonna link you my post below :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662839/change-title-of-bar-button-in-uiimagepickercontrollers-navigation-bar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code snippets above are both correct and have no issues. My assumption is that your issue lies elsewhere in creating the button that contains the image. The following code will create a button and will round it's corners, also I added the border to it in case you want to add that too. You can plug in the image you have in there as well. I have added a image of what this code will create for your reffrence also. Hope it will help you out.

```
  UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100,50);
  [btn setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [btn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:128.0/255.0f green:0.0/255.0f  blue:0.0/255.0f alpha:0.7]];
   btn.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 120.0, 50.0);//width and height should be same  value
   btn.clipsToBounds = YES;

   btn.layer.cornerRadius = 20;//half of the width
   btn.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
   btn.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;

   [self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Below is the image of the button that is related with the above code

[image]

Edit:

another way of doing the round corners is to use the method `masksToBounds` here is an example of it within the generic cell right out of the box from the template.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [object description];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"acolon.png"];
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
return cell;
}
```

here is the screen shot of the result:

[image]

i know you using a custom cell, so implement the `maskToBount` in the `cellForRowAtImdexPath` or wherever you are populating the `tableview` with its custom cells.

Comment: thanks for answer
the image and the button whose corners must be made rounded are properties of the UITableViewCell containing them. does this change anything? can i assign the button created by your code to the one I have as property? how, in the case? thanks

Comment: I guess your first code block is more suitable to my needs.
I copied-pasted it and I tried two different approaches: first, after the end of you code, i set chooseImageFromRoll = btn, where chooseImageFromRoll is my outlet button.
Then, I tried to substitute every occurrence of btn with chooseImageFromRoll. no solution worked