# Change title of bar button in UIImagePickerController's navigation bar

Tags: button, navigation, uiimagepickercontroller

my question is simple: how can i change change title of bar button in UIImagePickerController's navigation bar?
I created the controller for UIImagePickerController (triggered by the pressure onto a button) and then tried to modify its properties:

```
- (IBAction)chooseFromRoll:(id)sender {

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]){
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        imagePicker.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.42 green:0.18 blue:0.66 alpha:1.0];
        //imagePicker.navigationItem.title = @"Scegli foto profilo";

        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                  nil];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;


        [imagePicker.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  setTitle:@"Annulla"];
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

but nothing changed, only navigation bar was correctly modified.

Here's the code for function willShowViewController:

```
- (void) navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
    label.textAlignment = 2;
    label.frame = CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.origin.y, label.frame.size.width-200,label.frame.size.height);
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura" size:15.0];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0]];
    [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [label setText:@"Scegli foto profilo"];

    [navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:label.viewForBaselineLayout];

    [navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Annulla"];



}
```

can you tell me where's the mistake?

thanks

Comment: check my answer for the code snippet you needed to change the title of the nav bar in uiimage picker. Just change photos to whatever you need.

Comment: just added additional answers for your sub questions. hope that it will help you out man. if you are satisfied with my answers please check mark my answer and please let me know if you need any help with other questions. just make sure to post new questions and not add to the same question since it is not a good practice by SO standard. good luck my friend :)

Comment: for changing the back button title to italian when the uiimagepicker controler appears and the user tries to selct an existing image, you need to change the default language to italian through creating a new bundle in italian and set it as xcodes default language.

Comment: just google how to change the xcode's default language and you'll see there are a few tutorials on how to do it.when you accomplish that there is no need of subclassing the view that pops up through the imagepicker,it will be in italian and you cange the title of it as i showed you.here is one link http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/05/10/fixing-xcode-default-development-region.html,there are more out there. as far your question and sub questions in this page,i believe they are all been answered.if you have more questions please post a new one and i will look at it and will offer any help i can.

Comment: ok, thanks for help
in last couple of days, you have been enlighting :)

Comment: you are quiet welcome. i am looking forward to see more questions from you. dont forget to post the links for me so i get to see them, and dont forget to check my answer if you are satified with it. good luck and happy coding.:)

Comment: You checked your answer as the correct one, did you not use my answer ? I thought you said that you used my answer and it was helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a code snippet for twicking the title of the navigation bar in uiimage picker.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
UINavigationItem *ipcNavBarTopItem;

// add done button to right side of nav bar
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Photos"
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                              target:self 
                                                              action:@selector(saveImages:)];

UINavigationBar *bar = navigationController.navigationBar;
[bar setHidden:NO];
ipcNavBarTopItem = bar.topItem;
ipcNavBarTopItem.title = @"Photos";
ipcNavBarTopItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton;
}
```

Hope this would help you out.

**EDIT:**

the answer to first question is yes you can use the ibaction or just use the method i provided above to create the button, both should work. if you are using inaction, make sure you declare you controller within it so you can make it appear and dismiss it from within the action method. the answer to the second question if you want to change the title of the view that is presented when image picker from the photo album is presented then you need to create a new subview and pop it up to allow the user to select the desired image then you can change the title the way i did it above. lengthy process, i would not recommend it. the answer to the third question, try using the following code snippet where you declare your button,

```
[btn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13]];
```

where the btn is the name of your button and you can modify the font name and the size. i hope my answers can help you. good luck and let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it's always accurate.
just a couple of questions. the ACTION attribute in creating UIBarButtonItem should be, I guess, a function in the form **- (IBAction) selector:(id) sender**, right? This is what I did. I put in it the following: **[[recordPicker presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]**.
recordPicker is a property of the class, where I saved the UIImagePickerController I created, since otherwise the selector function wouldn't know which controller to dismiss. is it a correct procedure?

Comment: the second question is: as I told, I managed to change title of UIImagePickerController navigation bar when it's displayed. Anyway, when you select one photo album (for example, saved photos), you are driven to a new view, where title gets its original title, the back button on left points again to PHOTOS (it should do to new title I set before). I guess that even Cancel button will take again its default appearance. how can I modify this view too, to make it compliant with the first one appearing when UIImagePickerController is first presented?

Comment: one last question (they are many, I know, sorry):I need to make the cancel button in UIIMagePickerController appear like all the other buttons in my application, so I should set its font (for title) and size. do you know how to set font and the size of a standard iOS button used for cancelling purpose?

thanks and sorry again for taking advantage of your kindness.

Comment: thanks for your answers.
for what regards second question, I read on the internet that the title of navigation bar and cancel button of view displayed when an user enters an album to perform final choice of an image, are automatically set in the correct language by operative system.
my application should be in italian, at the beginning, so it's important to me that it happens for real. do you know anything about this topic? I changed the language of iOS simulator to italian, to make a test, but buttons' titles continue to be in english. so, even if the process is long, I guess I have no choice

Comment: ...anyway I didn't well understand the subview technique: could you explain it with some lines of code? I'm a still a newbie, even if i learnt a lot thanks to people like you, in last months, in fora.
moreover, I managed to change cancel button's title as you described, but when i get back from album using back arrow button (i didn't make any choice, then), my button turns again to english. why? can we avoid it?

thanks